# How to apply large scale landscape images

Tags: android, android-layout

Im developing an application in both landscape & portrait mode for normal and high screen resolution devices.

i used following folders to place normal and high screen resoluiton images

For Portrait mode

drawable-mdpi

drawable-hdpi

for Landscape mode

drawable-land for Normal images

Where i need to place high screen resolution images

I tried placing in drawable-large-land-hdpi folder but these images not taking in to the layout-land xml files.

Please let me know..

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try:

```
drawable-land-mdpi
drawable-land-hdpi
```